# Table View Hide Searchbar until scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I got a table view set up, and a working search bar - NO XIB OR STORYBOARD involved. Above the search bar I have label showing the numbers of entries in the table view and some other stuff. Well now I want the search bar + label hidden until the user scrolls up (like in Music App). This is the setup of my search bar

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.searchBar.frame.size.height,0, 0, 0);
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.searchBar];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,88) animated:YES];
[self.zsearchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

This is my label:

```
 tableCountDisplay = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -44, 155, 44)];
```

The label is already hidden until the user scrolls. The problem is - I can't get the search bar to hide. If I do

```
 [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,88) animated:YES];
```

Then search bar and label are hidden but also the first element of my table view...

If I do 44 or 0 (doesn't matter which of them)

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,44 or 0) animated:YES];
```

the label is hidden, and everything else is visible. Technically 0,44 should be the right offset, but it does not work for some reason. 
I'd be really happy about some help!

Comment: Why are you adding your searchBar as subView to self.view and after that setting the tableHeaderView? Shouldn't you just be setting the latter?

Comment: @Michael should I add it as a subview to view or as header to tableview? sorry I'm pretty new to xcode and learning step by step...

Comment: Hope my answer can get you in the right direction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the solutions is to add your `searchBar` and your `label` as subViews to a `UIView`. Then set this `UIView` as the `TableHeaderView`. My working sample looks like this:

[image: workingSample]

Screen before scrolling:

[image: beforescroll]

Screen after scrolling:

[image: afterscroll]

Comment: thank you so much for your effort, I was out of office until today and just tried - it worked perfectly fine! Without you I would've never got the idea to create a separate view so thanks a lot!

Comment: why don't put the code in your answer rather than the whole screenshot?

Comment: Just my humble philosophy at the time: you learn less from copy/paste compared to consciously typing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to maintain the header of a tableView fixed

1- could use an UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.

2- add subview (UIView) for header  (add the searchBarView in this view).

3- and add another subview for the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size.height ?? 0))
```

on `wiewWillAppear:` ;)